# Angular mat-select, Set different template for items list and selected item

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-option

I'm using a mat-option in Angular like this:

```
 <mat-select>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

I want the template in the list of the mat-select to be different from the template of the selected item in the mat-form-field.

for example, if I chose **Banana**, the mat-form-field will display  **you chose: Banana**
but the item in the list will still be just Banana.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using mat-select-trigger

and then inside you put whatever you want the template to be.

```
<mat-select-trigger>
      {{"you chose:" + GetSelectedName()}}
</<mat-select-trigger>
```

Comment: What is ...template ?

Comment: The template of the item you want to show